# Who wins in this simple coin-placing game?

Tags: geometry, circles, game-theory

We have an $m\times n$ rectangle. Two players take turns placing down diameter-$1$ coins that don't overlap with previously placed coins. Whoever cannot place a coin loses. Who wins?

[image]

(Note: coins are not required to fit neatly on a grid, so most turns will have uncountably many options.)

I'm fairly certain we *are* guaranteed a winner, even though the game tree has infinitely many vertices, because it's not infinitely deep: there's an upper bound to the length of a game, and if I recall correctly there's a general theorem that implies one player must have a winning strategy in such a case. I don't know how to determine what that winning strategy is, though, or who has it. Circle packings are pretty messy, so I'm not quite sure where to begin.

(For definitiveness, I will say that coins meeting at only one point - coins that are tangent - are allowed, though I am curious how the game changes if this rule is changed.)

Comment: If there is enough space for first coin first player will win. He can place first coin to center and then place every coin in position symmetric to move of second player.

Comment: See the answer I posted.

Comment: Your answer is correct for case when there is enough space for first coin.

Answer (score 4):

I realized this several minutes after posting this question. Player one wins. Player one plays in the center; forever after that, player one plays directly opposite player two.

EDIT: As Ivan Kaznacheyeu points out, this is assuming there is enough space for the first coin.

Comment: (Therefore, it does not matter if we allow tangencies or not.)